# Let $f(x,y)$ be function such that $\nabla f=0$ , prove if $g(x,y)=f(\frac {x}{x^2+y^2} , \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}) \Rightarrow \nabla g=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I tried to solve this question but couldn't reach the solution.
**My try :**
Lets set $u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \quad v=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$
So $g(x,y)=f(u,v)$ and by chain rule :
$$ g_x = f_u\bullet u_x+f_v\bullet v_x=f_u\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}+f_v\frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
$$g_y = f_u\bullet u_y+f_v \bullet v_y=f_u\frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}+f_v\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

So chain rule doesn't help much since we need to figure out what $\frac{df}{dv}$ and $\frac{df}{du}$ is.

How to proceed from here ?
should I have gone from a different direction?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note: You really want to use partial derivative notation here

Comment: Also, the gradient is a vector. Are you saying that $\nabla f$ is the $0$ vector everywhere or are you saying that $\nabla f$ is the $0$ vector at some particular point

Comment: @FShrike tried to edit :)

Comment: Nice (tip: you can use `\circ` for composition: $f_v\circ v_y$)

Comment: @FShrike The question didn't specify , I think its $0$ everywhere - which means $f_1 = h(y)$ and $f_2=t(x)$

Comment: This question is a bit of a strange one then. The exact details of $g$ do not even matter. If $g$ is any differentiable function and $f$ is any function with $0$ derivative at a point $x_0$, then $(g\circ f)'(x_0)=g'(f(x_0))\cdot f'(x_0)=0$ by the chain rule

Comment: Yes, $f_u = f_v =0$ by assumption, so $g_x=g_y=0$ in the calculations. This is true for any differentiable $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$. Also, @FShrike, why would we need to be composing those derivatives here? The bullets in the Roach's calculations are multiplications (as they should be).

Comment: @Glare , I though the same - that $f_u=f_v=0$ because we know $f_x=f_y=0$ , but why is it true?

Comment: That was my point roach; $f_u=0$ because $f_u$ is $f_x$ multiplied by something, i.e. $0$ multiplied by something, by the chain rule

Comment: I think your confusion is stemming from the notation. $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$ means $f_x(x,y) = 0$ and $f_y(x,y) = 0$. In this problem we have terms $f_u$ and $f_v$, but those are shorthand for $f_u(u,v)$ and $f_v(u,v)$ (consult a statement of the chain rule if you do not believe me). Assuming then that $\nabla f =0 $ on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, the difference between $f_u(u,v)$ and $f_x(x,y) = 0$ is merely a choice of letters. It might be better to think of $f_u$ as denoting "the partial with respect to the first slot" in this problem.

Comment: I think I understand now - we can prove $f(x,y)=c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$. so $f_u=0$ for any $u(x,y)$. Thank you.